# WARNING: Ignored class "Label" re-declaration

Tags: python, warnings, kivy, kivy-language

In order to make all labels' text support markup I use the following kivy-language code at the top of my kivy file:

```
<Label@Label>:
    markup: True
```

Later on when using:

```
<SomeWidget>:
    Label:
        text: '[b]Dog[/b]'
```

I get a label with the text `'Dog'` being bold as expected. Therefor, all my labels have `markup` set to `True` as expected.

However, I'm getting the following warning:

```
[WARNING           ] [Factory     ] Ignored class "Label" re-declaration. Current -  module: kivy.uix.label, cls: None, baseclass: None, filename: None. Ignored -  module: None, cls: None, baseclass: Label, filename: /home/Projects/gui/maingui.kv.
```

Why do I get this warning? Should I be doing something in a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
<Label>:
    markup: True
```

With the `@` notation you declare a new [dynamic subclass](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes) `Label` derived from `Label`.

It is useful to create a dynamic class like `<MyLabel@Label>:` in kv lang, in particular if a reference to the class is not needed later in python, to prevent any clashes that could arise from redefining behaviour (`Label` is used extensively in other default `Widget`s, and changing its properties in general might affect the look & feel of other widgets inadvertently).